# SSIS induced transform Error

Tags: excel, unicode, ssis

I am new too ssis and I have no clue what to make of this. All I want to do is get an excel file into an access database. the field types for the excel file are Unicode string[DT_WSTR] 255 and the schema for the access database is Unicode string[DT_WSTR] 255. The access database has some calculated fields, but are not used in the import.
Someone please help me. I do not know what to do.

> [OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (15). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their was a calculated find in the table. I did not Know SSIS did not allow calculated fields within the table